# Function return value (char and integer)

Tags: c++

I have a function that supposed to compute sum and return integer result, but it doesn't return the right value because when I multiply by 2 it takes value from ASCII table, not the integer value.

This part of the code is correct:
sum += *(ptrISBN + i) - '0'
, but when i try to multiply it by 2 it gives me ANSCII output, can someone help me to convert it into integer value somehow?

```
 int checkSum(char *ptrISBN)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
        if (isdigit(*(ptrISBN + i)))
        sum += *(ptrISBN + i) - '0' * 2;
    }   


    return sum;
}
```

Comment: you are mixing integers and strings

Comment: Can you please elaborate what an _ANSCII output_ is?

Comment: @bub what can I do then?

Comment: You can use parenthesis to fix that: `sum += (*(ptrISBN + i) - '0') * 2;`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks for the answer! it helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
 int checkSum(char *ptrISBN)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
        if (isdigit(*(ptrISBN + i)))
        sum += (*(ptrISBN + i) - '0') * 2; //little change here
    }   


    return sum;
}
```

I assume You wanted to convert character ('0' to '9') to its int value and then multiply it by 2.
Without change You were doing `sum += *(ptrISBN + i) - ('0' * 2);` which is not what You were looking for. That happened because multiplication was done before subtraction.

Comment: Better - but please also add why it happened in the first place (order of operations).